# Angularjs $stateProvider and singleton service issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-services

I am using angular-ui-router to make my app organized by routing but I am little confused. as I know I have to add 'ui-router' dependencie in module to use $stateProvider. but even though I do not add 'ui-router' dependencie, It is working well.

I know angular service is singleton object so if I add 'ui-router' dependencie only once. can I use $stateProvider service in any module?

below code is angular code defined in my app.

```
angular.module('app', ['ui-router','app.pages']);

angular.module('app.pages', ['app.pages.core']);


angular.module('app.pages.core',[])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('common.default', {
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                header: {
                    templateUrl: '/public/app/common/components/header/header.html',
                    controller: 'headerController'

                },
                content: {
                    template: '<div ui-view></div>'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('common.default.core', {
            url: "/goongles/",
            templateUrl: "/public/app/pages/core.html",
            controller: 'coreController'
        });
});
```

view code

```
<div ui-view="header"></div>
<div ui-view="content" class ='view ng-scope openm'></div>
```

please give me any idea. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it as a tree. The root of your tree is whatever module you set in the `ng-app` directive. When Angular it's bootstraping, it starts from there, and loads all of the module components and its dependencies' components. Once the bootstrap its finished, the lifecycle continues (creating constants, then providers, then running config blocks, etc).

Since somewhere in your app you have a dependency to `ui-router`, all of its services become available after bootstrap.

Regardless of that, you shouldn't rely on that for your modules to work. If you were to use your `app.pages.core` module in another application which doesn't have a dependency to `ui-router`, then it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an angular module, **always specify the dependencies used** in this module **even if you already specified the same dependency on another module**.

Remember that each module should be self sufficient and should work without relating on others module dependencies to be fully reusable.

So to answer correctly to your question .. yes you can use `$stateProvider` in any module, but add ui-router dependency in each of them.